# Not enough input arguments when using For Loop over an Integral

Tags: matlab, for-loop

When I run the following code in matlab, I get the "Not enough input arguments."

It is not clear to me what I am doing wrong. I have checked it over an over again, but obviously what I intend and what the computer says I intend do not match up.

```
tau = 50e-3;
b= 1;
dt = .2;
time=1:dt:100;
w = 1; W= w;
inte = zeros(1, length(time));
inte(1) = 0;
Ds = @(s) (w*s-s+b)*(1/tau);

for i=1:length(time)
   inte(i) = integral(Ds,0,time(i));   
end
```

My hope was that the loop would integrate with different values of time from the time array. Instead, it appears to be looping through and only integrating once.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Update to include full error message:

`% Validate the first three inputs.
narginchk(3,inf);
if ~isa(fun,'function_handle')
    error(message('MATLAB:integral:funArgNotHandle'));
end
if ~(isscalar(a) && isfloat(a) && isscalar(b) && isfloat(b))
    error(message('MATLAB:integral:invalidEndpoint'));
end
opstruct = integralParseArgs(varargin{:});
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);`

Comment: Your script should works smoothly. Try to put 'clear' command at the beginning.

Comment: Could we please get a full error message? "Not enough input" could be coming from anywhere.  And delete the `syms` line; it's not necessary here.

Comment: Code runs fine for me as well. MATLAB 2016b

Comment: Just some remarks: `time` is a poorly chosen variable name, because it is a function. Then, why is the function definition inside the loop? Finally I don't see the point in the numerical integration here anyhow?

Comment: @MendiBarel - I have put a clear at the beginning, but I am still getting the error message. Any other ideas?

Comment: @TroyHaskin - Thank you for your input, I will do that. I am still very new.

Comment: @nalyd88 - Interesting. I still cannot get it to run on mine. I am in RMATLAB2017a.

Comment: @Bernhard - Thank you for the advice. I am integrating the synaptic input of a neuron to demonstrate that for right value w, the function acts as a perfect integrator.